# How to upgrade dotnetnuke with existing database table

Tags: iis, dotnetnuke

I got a DOTNETNUKE project. I am new to DOTNETNUKE. My client has given me the files and folder with Database(say abc.mdf). I was said to upgrade their developed site from version 6 to latest version v7.0. The issue when upgrading is "**How to map the latest version to existing Database?**" ie: when I installed v7.0 in my system, it creates new database with 137 default tables. How am I supposed to map those 137 default tables, stored procedures, etc to existing database(abc.mdf) so that up-gradation happens easily with database.

I didn't find a proper solution for that.. 
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to map any tables OR files from new version to old version. Just follow up below steps to upgrade DNN website from old to new one. Here is the [reference link](http://kevalgangani.blogspot.in/2015/04/steps-to-upgrade-dnn-website.html).

1. Download **7.4.0 - Version Upgrade** file from [here](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/releases/view/611324).
2. Extract downloaded Zip file to root of your existing old version of DNN website. It is replacing all your old files with new one.
3. Run your website.
4. When you run your website, it will be automatically redirect to Upgrade Wizard page.
5. Just provide your **HOST** Username/Password and Click on Install button.
6. Now it will start process of mapping your old database tables & store procedures with new one.
7. After complete the process to 100%, click on Visit Website button.
8. Done. Your website updated.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: it didn't ask me for host username and password...it directly went to upgraded site..My site got upgraded.. VIsit your Website button. When I click there its throws error ..

Comment: and also am getting domain name does not exist in the database ... I just found that it is based on portalaliastable as I am opening my website using ip address.

Comment: Yes you have to add your domain in `PortalAlias` table. If you are in localhost try `localhost:123(PortNumber)` and for live add your original domain name `xyz.com`

Comment: PortalAlias table got many columns and few foreign keys(Portal table) too.. How am I supposed to add an entry manually in to that table?

Comment: Right click on table and select `Edit Top 200 Rows`. Now insert new row as PortalID=0, HTTPAlias=YourDomain, IsPrimary=True (Others False).

Comment: There is already PortalID=0 .. how to give new PortalID?? I should update in 2 tables Portals and PortalAlias as they are connected by foreign keys..

Comment: No need to update `Portals` table, just update `PortalAlias` not others.

Comment: ok but when I give portalID=0 HttpAlias=localhost/sitename.. it directs me to someother site... not my upgraded site ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76597/discussion-between-dexterity-and-sriram-ramachandran).

Answer (score 0):

DNN will do all that for you.

Extract the UPGRADE package over your existing site. Hit the site, login as host, run the Upgrade.

Comment: you mean v7.0 upgrade package... Do I need to install v6.0 to run through the files and folder because I didn't look up to those files..

Comment: No need to do intervals, just grab the latest one and use that